# 301 Redirect Changing Wrong Part of URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

In my .htaccess file i have the following redirects:

```
Redirect 301 /About-Us http://www.example.com/about-us
Redirect 301 /About-Us/Profile http://www.example.com/about-us/profile
```

The issue is that if the following address is typed in:

```
www.example.com/About-Us/Profile
```

The code above changes it to the following:

```
www.example.com/about-us/Profile
```

In short; it changes the first bit of the URL but not the second. How can I avoid this? I am aware of the `RedirectMatch 301 ^/folder/ /new-folder` rule for redirecting an entire folder, but this does not serve our needs. Also I am aware that capitalizing folders is not good practice. I did not build this site.

Comment: How did you go?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You need to add the `$` expression to the end of the parent folder, like so:

```
Redirect 301 /About-Us$ http://www.example.com/about-us
```

Then all child folders and files will redirect appropriately

Answer (score 0):

If all your URLs or, perhaps at least ones that aren't files should be lowercase, you may be better off with a single rewrite:

In `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [A-Z] LC.php [NS,L]
```

In `LC.php` (uppercase filename is deliberate)

```
<?php
$u = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$u[0] = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $u[0]);
header('Location: http://' . implode('?', $u), true, 301);
```

This has the advantage of being more robust by not having to preempt every possible combination of mixed case URLs. You don't have to use PHP, but you get the idea.